# I'm not able to reset my state array after I click a button

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
  const initialState = [...properties];
  const [location, setLocation] = useState('');
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const formattedDate = moment(`${startDate}`).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
  const [price, setPrice] = useState('');
  const [propertyType, setPropertyType] = useState('');
  const [filteredProperties, setFilteredProperties] = useState(properties);

  const resetState = () => {
    setFilteredProperties([...initialState]);

  };
```

I'm trying to build a filter as shown in the image. I want to reset the state every time I click search and then filter through the reset state but every time I click submit it filters the array and on the second submit never resets hence the array stays the same or goes empty depending on the second filter search.

Complete code here: https://github.com/Quelaan1/real_estate_search_filter/blob/develop/src/Components/Filter/Filter.tsx

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNqYW.png

Comment: Please share where `properties` is originating from, and where it gets changed/updated.

Comment: properties are originating from a JSON which has an array of Objects. Objects containing RealEstate property details.  The filter function should filter the array based on the filters used on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because state is taking time set the value. You can try with set the state to initial values at the end of component.

```
function filterer() {
  
  console.log(propertyType);

if (startDate) {
  setFilteredProperties(
    properties.filter(
      (property) =>
        !moment(`${formattedDate}`, 'MM/DD/YYYY').isBetween(
          moment(property.notAvailabeOn[0], 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
          moment(property.notAvailabeOn[1], 'MM/DD/YYYY')
        )
    )
  );
}

if (price) {
  console.log(filteredProperties);
  setFilteredProperties(
    properties.filter(
      (property) =>
        property.price >= parseInt(price.split('-')[0]) &&
        property.price <= parseInt(price.split('-')[1])
    )
  );
}

if (location) {
  setFilteredProperties(
    properties.filter((property) =>
      property.location.toLowerCase().includes(location.toLowerCase())
    )
  );
}

if (propertyType) {
  setFilteredProperties(
    properties.filter((property) => property.propertyType === propertyType)
  );
}
setFilteredProperties([...properties]);
}
```

Comment: I want it to reset before it filters.